# Some implicit constraint

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

When i execute this code(shown below) , it always sets implicit kind of constraint.

As you can see below , it always says that `D1 = D2` but there is no such explicit constraints nor any pattern matching which forces this.

Or in otherwords there is some reference between `D1` and `D2` such that whenever `D1` gets initialized, `D2` gets automatically initialized. I can't see how this is happening. Can someone explain me, i tried ot figure it out with debugger but it did not help.

It's a puzzle "GERALD + DONALD = ROBERT", initially three lists contains these variables.
[image]

I add code below if anyone wants to test it:

```
sum(N1,N2,N):-
    sum1(N1,N2,N,0,0,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],_).

sum1([],[],[],0,0,Digits,Digits).    
sum1([D1|N1],[D2|N2],[D|N],C1,C,Digs1,Digs2):-
    sum1(N1,N2,N,C1,C2,Digs1,Digs2),
    digitSum(D1,D2,C2,D,C,Digs2,Digs).

digitSum(D1,D2,C1,D,C,Digs1,Digs):-
    del(D1,Digs1,Digs2),
    del(D2,Digs2,Digs3),
    del(D,Digs3,Digs),
    S is D1 + D2 + C1,
    D is S mod 10,
    C is D div 10.

del(A,L,L):-
    nonvar(A),!.
del(A,[A|L],L).
del(A,[B|L],[B|L1]):-
    del(A,L,L1).
```

Query:

```
?- sum( [D,O,N,A,L,D], [G,E,R,A,L,D], [R,O,B,E,R,T] ).
```

Comment: You wrote **D is S mod 10,  C is D div 10.**. D is a value between 0 and 9 so  C is always 0. I think you wanted C is S div 10. To solve your problem, you should take a look at library clpfd.

Comment: With clpfd you can easily sove this problem, look at [this](https://github.com/triska/clpfd/blob/master/sendmory.pl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it says `D1 = D2` then you should see that both `D1` and `D2` have same variable from the list and List is a functor and one variable is visible in whole functor.

You should see that when the recursion ends, then you have have `D's`(last element) from `GERALD` and `DONALD` , since this D is visible in whole functor, `D1`  and `D2` both refer to same variable.

Comment: It means it will not find all solutions ?

Comment: It's true what you said! because there will a constraint automatically on the values of `D1` and `D2`, means if two variables are same then there values must also be same.