# Visibility of a variable inside a functor

Tags: prolog

Someone asked a question on this site and i noticed that if we have a list of lists which contain variables, then those variables are fully visible in outer list. For example

```
 [[D,O,N,A,L,D], [G,E,R,A,L,D], [R,O,B,E,R,T]]
```

For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745472/some-implicit-constraint)

Now the question was why there is a constraint that `D1 = D2`.

Person who asked this question also noticed it will not produce all possible solutions because when one of variable gets instantiated the other(same name) variable in other lists also get instantiated and this limits the number of solution.

I tried to find if there is any way to produce all possible solutions without changing the query but i think it is not possible because every variable in inner functors is also visible in outer functor.

So my question is is there anyway to produce all solutions without changing query?

Comment: This is  a puzzle that intentionally is constraining certain digits to be the same. So all of the `D` values are supposed to be the same, as are the `A` variables, etc. If, given that constraint, all of the solutions satisfying such constraints aren't being  found, then there's a problem in the logic of the predicate that is doing the addition.

Comment: Variable "visibility".... the scope of the variables is within a predicate clause. So all of the `D` variables *within a single predicate clause, including the  head of the clause* are the same `D`.

Comment: @lurker it restricts that sum of two variables should b equal to the third variable from third list but it does not say that first two variables should be same from first two lists. For example D's (last elements) from first two lists can be 1 and 3 and if we choose T as 4 then it satisfies all constraints.

Comment: But the problem is that it chooses either 1 for both D's or 3 for both D's. We can choose different values for D's and can find a solution and those solution will not be found with the code that he posted.

Comment: No that's not an issue. The fact that the original problem was stipulated with `D` in both places means that is an intended constraint. If you want them different, then that's a different problem. You're misunderstanding the problem being given, as is the OP for the link you posted. Different `D` values is not an acceptable solution to the problem since all `D` values are *intended* to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If having all instances of a variable in the same expression have the same value precludes any solutions, then no, the query would have to be changed to find those solutions.  This behavior of variables is pretty fundamental to Prolog.